# Using another thread in my application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, wcf

I have a Winforms application that hosts a WCF service.

Inside my `Connect` button click event, the connection is opening via `BackgroundWorker` in order to my UI responding while this connect s still in process (1 - 2 seconds) and after `BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` event go to my other class and do my stuff.

Recently I added few `Thread.Sleep` while debugging and notice that it does not freeze my UI so after I search I found that is maybe because of the `BackgroundWorker` thread (am I right ?)

In my application I have the form class and another class that contain several events, the form class subscribe to those event and update my UI in this way:

```
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            // Update UI
        });
```

So my question is: is it OK to use another thread in this way and to use `this.Invoke` ?

Or do I need to do it in another way ?

Comment: Even tho your approach is right, if you want to know a different way to handle UI updates without using Invoke I would recommend reading about SynchronizationContext. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is okay, its what background worker was invented for before the advent of async.

I recommend using [async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156513.aspx)

Comment: I personally do not recommend async, but that's OK. I have a pattern that results in slightly better behavior than async that I probably ought to extract into a library.

Comment: Yeah, that would be neat to see, if you want to throw it up on codeproject or something. Always looking for more things.